# Alloy UI Pagination not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, liferay-6, yui, alloy-ui

Im using Alloy UI for My Liferay 6.2 Portal, i have a DataTable with a pagination widget and everything works fine except for IE8 under Win XP. Apparently the browser is not rendering the YUI instructions to change the dom and is not loading the pagination.

Here's the code i use to create the pagination:

```
function esVisible() {
                var num_page = document.getElementById("numResultsPage").value;
                var visible = false;

                if (num_page < entradas.length && entradas.length > 0) {
                    visible = true;
                }
                return visible;
            }

            new Y.Pagination({
                boundingBox: '#pagination',
                circular:false,
                contentBox:'#pagination .pagination-content',
                cssClass:'miclase',
                page: 1,
                visible: esVisible(),
                on: {
                  changeRequest: function(event) {
                      dataTable.set('data', loadDataStore(xmlObject,event.state.page));
                  }
                },
                total:number_of_pages

              }).render();
```

And here's the code where i change the don elements to customize the pagination controls:

```
Y.one('.pagination-content .pagination-control:first-child').setHTML('<div><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-1x"></i></div>');   
              Y.one('.pagination-content .pagination-control:last-child').setHTML('<div><i class="icon-chevron-right icon-1x"></i></div>');
              //Ocultamos paginaciï¿½n interna (1,2,3..etc)
              Y.all('.pagination-content li:nth-of-type(n+2):nth-last-of-type(n+2)').addClass('ocultar');
              ocultar = Y.all('.ocultar');
              ocultar.setStyle('display','none');
              //
              prev = Y.one('.pagination-content li:first-child');
              next = Y.one('.pagination-content li:last-child');
              prev.setStyle('cursor','pointer');
              next.setStyle('cursor','pointer');
```

When i inspect the elements on IE8 all i got on the HTML is this:

```
<div class="pagination" id="pagination">
<ul class="pagination-content"/>
```

For some reason IE8 is not loading the pagination content on the contextbox. Help Please !

Comment: Compare it to the [sample code](http://alloyui.com/examples/pagination/real-world/)

Comment: mm well yeah that was the first thing that i did before asking

Comment: @Lowtrux, does the fix you found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099830/yui-on-ie8-argument-not-valid-on-dom-style-js) fix this issue?

Comment: Yes @stiemannkj1. Please apply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099830/yui-on-ie8-argument-not-valid-on-dom-style-js to fix this issue.